Non-computer-aided method to prove there is only one (9,3,1)-BIBD up to isomorphism?
I am working on a project to classify small BIBD up to isomorphism by hand. However, when I try to classify (9,3,1) BIBD up to isomorphism, there are about 20 situations to consider and I don't think it's a practical way by hand. So is there any clever method to prove there is only one such BIBD up to isomorphism?
I know there is only one (9,3,1) BIBD isomorphism class by,2-(v, k, λ) Designs of Small Order, Rudolf Mathon
Alexander Rosa. example I.22.
BIBD:A balanced incomplete block design (BIBD) is a regular, uniform, balanced design that is not complete.

I am surprized that you deny "computer help" in your title. You can in a first step use the public domain software "SAGE" which has a specialized library on BIBD :https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/designs/bibd.html, then nothing prevents you to find back these results using your pencils/erasers, etc.

@JeanMarie I am new to sagemath. In the official documents, it tells how to find a BIBD. But  I don't know how to find all isomorphism classes of a BIBD with given parameters? Web searching helps little.

I am sorry not to be able to advise you on the BIBD library of Sage just because I know too few things on this subject.

I don't know if it is of interest for you : the (9,3,1) BIBD is mentionned in these slides : https://www.site.uottawa.ca/~lucia/courses/7160-17/slides/01IntroToBlockDesigns.pdf
